# Create a simple table in Matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

I've been fighting with fprintf for an hour now, should be easy but it's not apparently.
Have a vector with descriptive statistics called `datasave`, contains 9 numbers like average, standard dev, kurtosis etc.

And I have a vector `datalabels` with the lablels 'Average' , 'St.dev', 'Kurt' etc.

Open a file with fileopen
print the labels
new line
print the values ( exactly under the labels!)
close the file

This is what I've tried so far:

```
fileID = fopen('descstat2.txt','w'); 
fprintf(fileID,'MediaTonnes MinTonnes MaxTonnes Sigma Skew Kurt SigmadTonnes SkewdTonnes KurtdTonnes\r\n');
format short;
fprintf(fileID, '%g\t%g\t%g\n', datasave.');
```

Help?

I have at least 50 different combinations so I can't really give you my output...

Comment: Please post some of the code you have tried

Comment: I tried this: fileID = fopen('descstat2.txt','w');
>> fprintf(fileID,'MediaTonnes   MinTonnes  MaxTonnes  Sigma  Skew  Kurt  SigmadTonnes SkewdTonnes KurtdTonnes\r\n');
>> format short;
>> fprintf(fileID, '%g\t%g\t%g\n', datasave.');

Comment: What is `%g`? Why not `%f`? Secondly why only three % signs if `datasave` hold 9 numbers?

Comment: sorry...I actually have no idea what I'm doing, trying to read mathwork specs without understanding any of it, will try as u suggest...

Comment: To align all the numbers to the columns you need to add an extra `'\t'` between each of the column headings in the first `fprintf`.

Comment: Also take a look at `dlmwrite`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
fileID = fopen('descstat2.txt','w'); 
fprintf(fileID,'%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\r\n', datalabels);
fprintf(fileID, '%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\r\n', datasave);
fclose
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, I think your first suggestion is good enough, that way I can import the "table" in excel...nine times % and using f (but what is f?)

Comment: Are you trying to export to excel?? So firstly if it's just 1 nine element vector you can just double click it to open it in the variable editor and literally copy and paste in into excel. Secondly look at `xlswrite` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html or `dlmwrite` like I suggested. They do the work for you!

Answer (score 1):

To use XLSWRITE you need to create a cell array:

```
out = [datalabels(:)'; num2cell(datasave)];
xlswrite('descstat2', out)
```

If the file you are saving to is exist as a text file, `xlswrite` will save it as a text as well.

It probably will be slower that `fprintf` (due to COM interface) but you don't have to deal with formatting the output. Just need to convert everything to cells.

---

Another option is to use TBLWRITE from Statistical Toolbox. You can just do:

```
tblwrite(datasave, datalabels, [], filename, '\t')
```

It will also put row numbers or labels specified as 3rd argument. Might be useful for some data.